# How can I remove a retaining wall made of vertical landscape timber?

Tags: wood

I have VERTICAL landscape timbers in the hard soil in the back yard and I want to remove them.

What is the best way to remove this retaining wall?

Comment: Pics or it didn't happen. (Or... you won't get a good answer.)

Answer (score 1):

If they are vertically embedded in the soil, and if you can get heavy chains wrapped around them individually, you might be able to lift with something like the bucket of a backhoe or a loader.

Alternatively, you can remove the soil around them with a backhoe or even with hand tools. In either case, you're likely to have to pry them apart. Landscape timbers in a retaining wall are often held together with embedded pieces of rebar. When I removed my wood retaining wall, I used a 2x4 as a pry bar.

Comment: Go with a mini excavator or backhoe. You can rent one starting around $200 a day.  Its safer alot less work and you will need something to slope the dirt around once the wall is removed.

Comment: Good suggestion. On my project I had to do a lot of hand digging due to proximity of utilities.